# cannot force linux autostart script file

Tags: ubuntu, kde, xinput, plasma, autostart

I need to force my KDE Plasma installed on ubuntu 18.04 to run the following script on startup:

```
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Finger touch" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen stylus" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen eraser" eDP-1-1
```

So I've put it in

- /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
- crontab -e
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- maybe some other places that I forgot

I've also created a *.sh with these 3 lines and put it in the settings->autostart in the "desktop file" section and in the "script file" section. In the latter one I put it twice: under "startup" option and under "before session start-up" option. I put it in the settings->login screen (sddm) "advanced" tab -> commands -> "reboot command" section. I put it with and without the "root" and "sudo" prescriptions, I put it everywhere I could where I could only find on the internet and it does not work. But when I execute exactly the same lines in the terminal manually it works!!!